# malloc cpu cycles

Tags: c

What is the cost of malloc(), in terms of CPU cycles?
(Vista/OS, latest version of gcc, highest optimization level,...)

Basically, I'm implementing a complex DAG structure (similar to a linked list) 
composed of some 16B (less common) and 20B nodes (more common).

Occasionally, I will have to remove some nodes and then add some.
But, rather than always using malloc() and free(), I can simply move
unneeded nodes to the end of my data structure, and then update the
fields as my algorithm continues. If a free node is available, I will
update the fields; if not, I'll have to allocate a new one.

The problem is, I might have only one free node available while having
to input, for example, 20 nodes worth of data. This means:

- I will check for an available free node
- The check will succeed, and that free node will get updated
- I will check for an available node 19 more times
- All checks will fail, and malloc() will be called each time

Question: Is it really worth it? Should I just malloc() and free() as usual,
or is it worth it to keep some free nodes available at the end of the list,
and keep checking even if it will usually fail and lead to malloc() anyway?

More concretely,

*What is the CPU cost of malloc()??*

Comment: Why not always allocate, say 20 new nodes each time you run out of free nodes and leave the remaining 19 unused nodes as free noodes?

Comment: If you are really worried about malloc overhead, which usually is not a problem IMO, try VirtualAlloc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms918445.aspx   There is no one generic answer to the cpu cycle question you ask.  There platform complications.  If you have to know, you will probably have to call QueryPerformanceCounter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=VS.85).aspx  to time your malloc-ing

Comment: Huh, are you serious about VirtualAlloc? It rounds up all allocations UP to the page size (4kB). So each time he asks for 20B, 4kB will effectively be allocated. Plus, VirtualAlloc must trap to kernel mode, and is thus likely much slower than malloc.

Comment: @zvrba: OK he allocates a page and divides it up into 20 byte chunks and then when he's run out of these, he allocates another page.

Comment: @Warren: lots of room for help, no? The OP might lack knowledge, but seems to show a desire to learn.

Comment: Use `malloc`, profile your application, and if your performance is not accaptable, think of better solution;)

Comment: Cashing old nodes is a good way to get around a bad malloc implementation, but it may not win you anything.  It won't lose you much, though.  I suggest using a stack for this b/c it's O(1) add and remove, and keep a separate one for each thread so that you don't have to fight over access to it.  Then if one of your stacks gets too high you can free some nodes.  If a stack is empty when you need a node you just malloc a node.

Answer (score 21):

Does it matter what it costs? Really?

The true answer is "it depends".

It depends on loads of things

- What else the OS is doing at the time
- How fragmented memory has become
- speed of the memory and processor on the client PC
- etc

If this code is massively performance critical, them **time everything** you can and work out the best pattern for your usage case.

If it is isn't the most performance critical bit of code, just do whatever is the **clearest and simplest to implement and maintain**.

*"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil", Donald Knuth*

Comment: Also, it is impossible to say, what it costs, in CPU cycles. It is also impossible to say, what a CPU cycle will be, in milliseconds. You did not specify a CPU type, or speed, an instruction set/architecture, or anything. The answer for a 25 Mhz ARM7TDMI will be orders of magnitude different for a given chunk of C code, from a 2.6 ghz Intel Core 2 duo.    Why are you thinking about Cycles, when you aren't even thinking about (or telling us) about your CPU, and why you even CARE about cycles?

Comment: Oh yes, verily. Heap Fragmentation is one of the major performance hits applications wiht complex, changing data structures - which also means asking for the cost of a single allocation is the wrong question. ---  While I admire Knuth, I believe his 36 years old quote is misused here.

Comment: I don't think it's misused. The sentiment rikh puts forward is definitely appropriate. "If it's important, measure. If it's not important enough to measure, don't optimise."

Comment: It can matter.  It's very easy to implement very poor performance `malloc` and `free`, but unless you're using a code size optimized version or one from someone you've never heard of it's probably pretty good for general cases.  Though there are lots of times when people think that their algorithm has better big O performance than it actually does due to their use of malloc and free.

Comment: @Ian: misused in the sense that it's not a small efficiency (say, replacing an int-swap with three XOR's), but a major scalability issue.

Comment: @peterchen: Unless you know a lot more about the OP's application than I do, I don't think you can say for sure it's a "major scalability issue". Once you've identified a bottleneck you measure, optimise, measure again, and then you know for sure that you've improved the performance. That's the essence of the Knuth essay. If you don't measure, you're just guessing.

Comment: @Iain: An educated guess can fix your design before any code is written. Knuth wrote that essay back when memory access times were constant and could keep up with the CPU, execution times could be determined by adding up the "cycles" column in the instruction table, parallel execution was an administrators choice, not the norm. On how manys machines do you typically measure? If my CPU has halfthe cache size of yours, will I hit a speedbump at half, a quarter or an eights your data set? Heap *is* a scalability issue waiting to happen - not if, when.

Comment: @peterchen: Yes, but does your design need fixed? Did you optimise for the right thing? Knuth also said "It is often a mistake to make a priori judgements about what parts of a program are really critical, since the universal experience of programmers who have been using measurement tools has been that their intuitive guesses fail." That's just as true today as it was then.

Comment: I have been surprised by profiling results often enough to understand that. The problem I have with "only measuring tells the truth" is: it's to late: fixing a design bug in a profilable application is expensive, keeping in mind the *possibility* of a custom allocator for key objects often costs close to nothing. Also, Knuth's often quoted as an excuse to completely ignore performance until the product is in beta. Fortunately, our computers are fast enough to make that a non-issue most of the time.

Comment: (sorry for my verbosity) To reiterate my core objection: Knuth offered the quote in the context of linear optimization benefit (reordering a loop to be about 12% faster). Heap fragmentation and working set are highly nonlinear brickwalls. They are still a non-issue for most programs, but not in the sense of Knuth's paragraph in that paper. (I probably should have been clearer on that).

Comment: @peterchen: Absoloutely, keep the *possibility* in mind. Keeping allocation segregated as per your answer below is an excellent plan. That comes under "simplest to maintain" though, right?

Answer (score 5):

malloc() does not have a fixed cost in terms of latency because of the numerous possible states the memory manager has to deal with to fulfill your request.

Since your node sizes are relatively small, you should consider always doing an allocation of some larger size, perhaps 10 or more node sizes per allocation and stuffing the extra ones into your unused pool.  That way you'll incur allocation uncertainly less frequently.  But more importantly, you'll reduce the amount of memory fragmentation caused by so many tiny allocations.

Incidentally, I don't consider this sort of design consideration "Premature Optimization" since you aren't looking for an excuse to inject obtuse design characteristics without good reason.  Data structures which can grow to arbitrary size and persist for arbitrary durations do need a little bit of forethought.

Particularly since data structures tend to find their way into unplanned usages later and often by other developers, it is important to strike a reasonable balance in terms of clarity and anticipated behavior.

Write your structure proper with your own allocation and deallocation functions.  Implement those separately.  Initially have them just malloc and free a single node to make debugging easier.  Later you can redesign them with fancier algorithms as your needs dictate.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it really worth it?

You will have to measure in order to know, period.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Premature optimisation is bad. Writing maintainable code, so that you can easily optimise later if you need to, is a much better option. A type-specific malloc function that, initially, just calls malloc for you (and similar for free) might not be a bad idea - a single point of change if you do decide you need some custom allocation strategy later. The initial trivial function should be automatically inlined, so there is no cost for this.

Comment: +1. This "oh, malloc costs N cycles" leads absolutely nowhere. It costs N cycles, so what? The no-op in the endless loop costs nothing, yet the endless loop runs *forever*.

Comment: @sharptooth - well, yes, the loop costs infinite cycles. The cost of the nop isn't the same as the cost of the loop. Context is essential, though - a cycle count for the malloc means nothing if you don't know the costs of other operations. To me, the big reason to not go around writing custom allocators is they often don't like staying simple in practice - if you're not careful, you can end up writing your own second-rate heap implementation which is much slower than the original anyway.

Comment: @Steve314: I think you misunderstood @sharptooth's comment. I think he meant that the cost of `malloc()` (or `no-op`) means nothing without knowing the context it's used in. If used in a tight loop a million times, even a `no-op` takes too much time. If called once per program run, it doesn't matter what `malloc()` costs.

Comment: @sbi - yes, but the cost of the whole loop is still distinct from the cost of one iteration. Much fewer iterations of malloc will be needed to cause a fixed delay, for instance, than of nop - because malloc is costlier (per call) than nop. Yes, you need to measure to know where your hotspots are, but you still need some understanding of the relative cost of operations. Otherwise, when you find your hotspot, how are you going to know what to try to optimise it? Your "optimisation" could end up slower than the original.

Comment: @sbi - BTW - I was recently surprised by a cycle-counts list for memory accesses, synchronisation operations etc on this site. It turns out that certain sync operations are much cheaper than I thought. This probably *will* affect my coding. I don't plan to memorise those cycle counts, but a better understanding of relative per-call costs means I can make more intelligent decisions. Context issues such as call frequency aren't just inherently there - the context is what it is because of the choices we make, and those choices are influenced by our understanding of relative per-use costs.

Answer (score 2):

If memory is never freed, malloc() will tend to run pretty fast.  If many blocks of memory are used and freed, malloc() may become quite slow.  The particulars of how fast or slow it will be for any given pattern of usage depend strongly upon the implementation, and sometimes only slightly-less strongly on the phase of the moon.

In some cases, particularly with embedded systems, memory usage will strictly follow a LIFO pattern.  In that case, it may be helpful to simply grab all the memory one might want to use (on embedded systems this can often be done at link time), and keep a pointer to the start of that area and the end of allocated space (which initially is the start of the area).  To allocate 'n' bytes, simply copy the end-of-allocated-space pointer, add 'n' to the original, and return the copied value.  To free up a chunk and everything allocated after it, copy the address of the chunk to the end-of-allocated-space pointer.

Note that this approach has zero per-block overhead, and that both allocation and deallocation are very cheap.  The LIFO limitation might be a problem, but if most of the usage is LIFO and one explicitly knows everything that needs to persist after a "sweep", one may be able to relocate everything that needs to be kept after a "sweep" to the start of allocable space, and put the pointer after the relocated stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @rikh highlighted, if you want ultra fast memory allocation, one technique is to pre-allocate blocks that are the size you need (lots of them).

I've written custom memory managers that have pre-allocated lists of blocks of different sizes.

In addition, you can also incorporate a memory bounds checking scheme into the blocks you are managing.

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment. Or was it just a revenge downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into pooled allocators; AT&T's [`vmalloc`](http://www2.research.att.com/~gsf/download/ref/vmalloc/vmalloc.html) package provides pooled allocator for example.

Answer (score 1):

Heaps, especially for small memory allocations, a often structured as a linked list, where each heap cell points to the next. When allocating memory, the allocator will walk the heap until it finds a cell big enough for the required allocation. As your memory becomes more fragmented, you will have to walk a larger and larger number of cells. Although a large amount of work has been done to minimize allocation times, it is better to avoid the problem all together.

It may well be a good idea to allocate a large block and divide this amongst a number of list items. this will probably mean you have fewer cache misses when walking your linked list.

For this reason, I would avoid the high frequency use of malloc and free and add the extra complexity of a freelist.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth finding out what the minimum allocatable block is in your target OS. You may be better off malloc()ing in 4K blocks and using that as your unused pool.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for the cost of a single `malloc` is the wrong question.

Usual performance degradation factors are:

- Size of working set (how many bytes you are "touching" within e.g. a second)
- Memory fragmentation (how long does it take malloc to find a suitable block, and how much will this increase working set size)

From my experience, when you have to expect many nodes of that size (>~ 100K...Millions), these things do matter.

**Custom Allocator**
Of course, if you can tune your algorithm to use less memory, or less nodes, do so. However, instead of letting the allocation cost concern leak into your solution, isolate it in a custom allocator.

The simplest choice for that would be overloading new for your class, this means your solution code is not affected.

Which allocator depends a bit on the needs of the algorithm. For frequently allocating and freeing same-sized blocks, a [fixed-size pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) is the canonical choice.

An [arena allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349313/lock-free-arena-allocator-implementation-correct) can perform even better if you have many allocations and very few deletes (i.e. you can afford to not release the memory that was freed).

However, the deciding factor between the two is usually locality of reference. If there's anything you can do to boost that, you can win big time.

Comment: Good answer. As you say, *if* you know it matters, it can really matter. It's a very good idea to isolate the problem area so you can tweak later without affecting the rest of your code.

Answer (score -3):

Any advice above that urges you to try some specific technique is wrong. The advice above that tells you to avoid premature optimization (a very important principle indeed), is right.

You have given us a question which is meaningless.  What CPU? What speed? What architecture?   Malloc is a C function. What implementation of the standard heap routines are you talking about? The one in Microsoft Visual C/C++? The one that comes with GNU standard libraries (stdlibc) on Linux/Unix/Posix?

You haven't measured your performance and then told us what the performance under load is, you didn't tell us you wrote unit tests for load testing. Are you doing your initial design and your "thinking about how many cycles" at the same time? Because that's just silly.

Comment: To state unequivocally that any advice is wrong unless it is "what I know to be the one true right way" detracts somewhat from your credibility.

Comment: The question does say Microsoft Vista, and latest GCC (which would be more convincing with a version number).  It doesn't mention which libraries - that I'd grant you.

Comment: Like vista has any effect on CPU speed at the cycle level?  If I cared about this issue, I would dig into the standard C libraries and look at the malloc function, and then use GCC to generate ASM from the .C sources and then look at its performance. Or I could just measure it instead of asking other people to measure something that might not agree with my setup.